# Synonym for "too optimistic"

Tags: synonyms

In research paper I use the following two sentences:

1. However, this is too optimistic definition since the allowable range of perturbations is restricted to diagonal matrices.
2. However, this definition is too optimistic because it does not allow independent loop gain changes.

Even though, they are in two different paragraphs, they sound similar and repetitive.

Is it possible to change two words "too optimistic" in the first sentence without changing the meaning of the sentence? Note: I cannot use word "unrealistic".

Comment: What are you trying to convey by the word "optimistic"?

Comment: Are you just trying to avoid sounding similar and repetitive? For scientific writing, there is nothing wrong with sounding similar and repetitive. Just be as clear as possible.

Comment: @Dan something equivalent to naive, but I don't want to sound negatively about previous works. Thus I try to avoid words like unrealistic or naive.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by naive definition. Could you give an example of a word, and a naive definition of that word?

Comment: @Dan for example trying to approximate a parabola f(x)=x^2 with another function f(x)=a|x|, where "a" is a variable. Of course, you can do it, but it is too optimistic approximation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is always the productive prefix *over-*, so you can use ***overoptimistic*** (*over-optimistic*). Eminent English writers like Shakespeare used or introduced many words prefixed with *over-* also, like *overcool, overeye, overhold, overred, oversize, oversnow* etc. (some are obsolete).

The adjective *over-optimistic* is listed in *OED* also with the first usage from 1894. It can be used for both people and abstract things. *OED* lists the noun *over-optimism* from 1898.

*[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/overoptimism)* defines *overoptimism* as:

> an excessive or unrealistic degree of optimism

and includes the adjective *overoptimistic* with the example:

> *overoptimistic* projections for the future

and also includes the adverb *overoptimistically*.

Comment: that is actually the word I was looking for, thanks

Comment: I think it benefits from the hyphen, making it easier to parse (ove roptimism?). But this is a good word.